# Using FingerprintJS properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fingerprintjs

I`m not a experience still in the React.js but I'm want to write some application using FingerprintJS.

```
    function App() {
  let app_visitorId = 'Is not defined still';
  (async () => {
    // Get the visitor identifier when you need it.
    const fp = await fpPromise
    const result = await fp.get()
    // This is the visitor identifier:
    const visitorId = result.visitorId;
    const confidence = result.confidence;
    console.log(
        '----------------------------------------------------------\n' +
        'fingerprintjs@ visitorId: ' + visitorId + '\n' +
        'fingerprintjs@ confidence: ' + confidence.score.toPrecision(6) + '\n' +
        '----------------------------------------------------------\n');
  })();
  return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.<br/>
            {app_visitorId}
          </p>
          <a
              className="App-link"
              href="https://reactjs.org"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
  );
}
```

My question is: how I can change 'app_visitorId' let for render its value in the render block ?
Thank Your!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook, store the `vistitorId` to the state using [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).
In the render (return function) check if the state variable was already populated since returned value comes from an async promise. If so, render the `visitorId`.

You can check the more complex code solution using Next.js (but the concept is the same as with React) at [GitHub](https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs-pro-use-cases/tree/main/pages/credential-stuffing).
Alternatively, one can check [Fingerprint Pro's React library](https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs-pro-react).

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded fingerprint v3, then used it as below:

```
import fpPromise from "./fingerpintv3";

// Get the visitor identifier when you need it.
    const fp = fpPromise.load();

    fp
      .then((fp: any) => fp.get())
      .then((result: any) => {
        const visitorId = result.visitorId;
        console.log('fingerprint: ', visitorId);
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```